# Why ifstream getline is crashing

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, c++17

I wrote what I thought a quite basic function to read a file.  But for a reason I dont know, the `std::getline` crashes my application, with this output :

> The program '[14092] ASREngineApp.exe' has exited with code -1073740777 (0xc0000417)

My code

```
std::vector<std::string> readFile(const std::string& fileName)
{
    //Read file
    std::vector<std::string> fileLines;
    std::ifstream file;
    file.open("toto.txt", std::ios::in);
    if (!file)
    {
        //problem file NULL
        //return error
    }
    else if (!file.is_open())
    {
        //file not open
        //return error
    }
    else
    {
        //file opened
        std::string str;
        while (std::getline(file, str)) //this line crashes
        {
            fileLines.push_back(str);
        }
    }
    return fileLines;
}
```

1. I triple checked and yes, toto.txt if a file that exists beside my application.
2. I read this answer [C++: ifstream::getline problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4704097/c-ifstreamgetline-problem).  This following snippet is also crasing: `std::copy(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file),std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(),std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));`
3. I tried ofstream and I am able to create a file in the same folder where I am trying to open and read toto.txt
4. I also double checked the permission of toto.txt, everything looks good.
5. Compiling with vs2017
6. Function like `file.eof` and `file.is_open` are not crashing, but function like `file.tellg` and `file.seekg` are crashing.

### EDIT, more information, problem is the ifstream constructor

It looks like the problem is coming from `std::ifstream` constructor.

See this debug output from my little working application with only the readfile function called from a main:
[image]

Then, the following is the debug output from the same function, in my real big application:
[image]

So, why in this case, `_Mychar` is equal to `-52'Ì'`.  This value should be '\0'

Comment: 1. Your error is in some other place. 2. You don't need `!file.is_open`.

Comment: Your function never uses its `fileName` argument. So why does it take one in the first place?

Comment: I can't reproduce https://wandbox.org/permlink/qFBbXqa1IamP11Ln

Comment: Maybe there is some type of undefined behavior in your program before you open this file that causes the heap to be corrupt or some other type of corruotion.

Comment: Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55138498/how-can-i-debug-the-cause-of-a-0xc0000417-exit-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55138498/how-can-i-debug-the-cause-of-a-0xc0000417-exit-code)

Comment: "yes, toto.txt if a file that exists beside my application" - that it exists in the same location as your executable is not what is important. Your program tries to open the file from its current working directory. That is *not necessarily* the same as the directory your application is in, depending on how it was started and whether or not the program programmatically changed its CWD at run time.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I also tried with an absolute path, I have the same crash.  Really, this doesn't make sense....

Comment: I don't believe the code displayed is the problem. My advice is to create a new small example program and see if it still exhibits this failure. If your small example program still crashes then its time to try reinstalling Visual Studio.

Comment: @drescherjm Did a small project with just the snippet above and it worked.  So, you are right, the problem is coming from somewhere else.  But how can I debug this strange problem?

Comment: First step is to turn the warning level up and check for compiler warnings. A second step could be a bit of calling the function at different places in your program seeing where it is working and where it causes a crash.